# View page source vs HTTPURLConnection

Tags: java, html

This might be a silly question whose answer is obvious... But am not able to get it.

I am trying to read the webpage srouce using java program as shown below:

```
URL url = new URL(urlValue);
HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
BufferedInputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(urlc.getInputStream());
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
byte[] by = new byte[1024];
int byteRead;
while ((byteRead = buffer.read(by)) != -1){
    builder.append(new String(by, 0, byteRead));
}
buffer.close();
```

This is all working fine, and I can see the page source... 
When I open the same url in browser and right click on it and view page source. The page source from java program is not the same as what I see from browser.

I just want to know the reason for this. 
Am I missing something? 
What should I do to get the exact same result from java program?

Thanks, 
Irfan

Comment: What differences? View source reveals changes made by the browser during the rendering process & in some cases alterations to the dom made by script, for example IE will strip quotes around attributes & normalize case ...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the website logic it is also possible your application to be filtered by User-Agent.

Try to put different "User-Agent" header.

The other reason for not getting the right page is that the you don't handle redirects. For example if you open wsj.com, your browser is automatically redirected to online.wsj.com. In order to manage such situations take a look in apache httpclient library, where this functionality is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think your page have a references to other pages inside. And while your browser read documents by these references automatically, you should parse html you've got and read references manually (or use some framework)
2. Web site (urlValue) can understand that you are robot (by User-Agent) and do not return content of page. Try to sniff your connection via tcpmon.

Comment: I am trying the same thing using htmlUnit...I get similar result like java program with that as well...

Answer (score 0):

I would not do this.

`builder.append(new String(by, 0, byteRead));`

Instead, read all the bytes into a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and then convert to String.

In case of UTF-8 or similar charsets, one symbol is not always one byte. The last byte read into your buffer may be part of a multibyte character. When you convert to String, the String may not be correct since last character is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

```
urlc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36");
```

By adding this line will solve your problem. I am research on this area and I found no solution in this topic as yet ended up I tried various method and this shows what I want.